# Java fx Changing the Color of a String

Tags: java, javafx

In my Program i have to change the color of a sample string by clicking on the radio Buttons. But i keep getting errors every time i click on them. i keep getting this error. I am also using e(fx)clipse to code this.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javafx.graphics@10.0.2/javafx.scene.paint.Color cannot be cast to
>   javafx.graphics@10.0.2/javafx.scene.text.Text     at
>   employee.view.MainController.colorRadioButtonSelected(MainController.java:83)
>       package employee.view;

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontPosture;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;

public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private BorderPane myPane;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton blackRadioButton;

    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup colorToggleGroup;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton redRadioButton;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton blueRadioButton;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton greenRadioButton;

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> mylistView;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox boldCheckBox;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox italicCheckBox;

    String Text;
    Text sample=new Text(50,300,"SAMPLE");
    FontWeight weight = FontWeight.NORMAL;            //   FontWeight.BOLD is boldface
    FontPosture posture = FontPosture.REGULAR;       //    FontPosture.ITALIC is italic
    int size=18;
    boolean fontBold = false;
    boolean fontItalic = false;

    public void initialize() {
        blackRadioButton.setUserData(Color.BLACK);
        redRadioButton.setUserData(Color.RED);
        greenRadioButton.setUserData(Color.GREEN);
        blueRadioButton.setUserData(Color.BLUE);
        myPane.getChildren( ).add( sample );
        sample.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", weight, posture, size));     
    }   

    @FXML
    void boldCheckBoxSelected(ActionEvent event) {
    }

    @FXML
    void colorRadioButtonSelected(ActionEvent event) {
        sample= (javafx.scene.text.Text) colorToggleGroup.getSelectedToggle().getUserData();
    }

    @FXML
    void italicCheckBoxSelected(ActionEvent event) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you update the title to be more relevant to your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the data as `Color`

```
blackRadioButton.setUserData(Color.BLACK);
redRadioButton.setUserData(Color.RED);
greenRadioButton.setUserData(Color.GREEN);
blueRadioButton.setUserData(Color.BLUE);
```

But you try to cast it as `Text`

```
(javafx.scene.text.Text) colorToggleGroup.getSelectedToggle().getUserData();
```

To fix this you can use a switch statement or multiple if statements to set `sample` object depending on which colour is selected. Example if statement:

```
if ((Color) colorToggleGroup.getSelectedToggle().getUserData() == Color.BLUE) {
    sample = new Text(50, 300, "Something");
}
```

Alternatively you can set the data for the radio buttons as `Text`, for example:

```
blueRadioButton.setUserData(new Text(50, 300, "Something"));
```